# Produce bounding boxes from binary masks

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, mask, bounding-box

I have some binary images containing black pixel-level masks and I need to retrieve the coordinates of bounding boxes around each mask. I need a bounding box for every single mask, masks are always separated by at least one pixel and images are always binary.

Example crop of a mask image:

[image]

I have used `contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(binary, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)` to detect contours and then derive coordinates of bounding boxes around detected contours:

```
def generateBB(maskImage):
    _, binary = cv2.threshold(maskImage, 225, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(binary, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2:]
    
    with open(os.path.join(filePath, "Name" + ".txt"), 'w') as f:
        for c in contours:
            M = cv2.moments(c)
            x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
     
            if M['m00'] != 0:
                cx = int(M['m10']/M['m00'])
                cy = int(M['m01']/M['m00'])
            
            xCoord = (x+w/2)
            yCoord = (y+h/2)
            width = w
            height = h
        
            f.write(f'{xCoord} {yCoord} {width} {height}\n')
```

This works well but not perfectly: Specifically, when there are several small masks close to each other the function may group them together in one bounding box. Are there alternative arguments to `cv2.findContours` that can solve this issue? Or do I need some other solution?

Comment: use connectedComponents first, and work separately on each component. Use minAreaRect for the bbox.

Comment: Thanks, @Miki. Could you elaborate a bit? Does connectedComponents detect each individual mask?

Comment: @Miki is refering to [this](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.label) (or some equivalent), and his suggestion is exactly the way to go.

Comment: @Miki - maybe turn your comment into an answer...

Comment: **show** us your result. draw a picture. -- findcontours and CC will find the same blobs. if "multiple blobs" are recognized as a single blob, it *is* a single blob. -- you seem to ask about morphology operations.